# How can i track the issue in production RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

have on pdf creating function, but that PDF Generation different response, in local development working fine but the server shows 500 error. how can i track the issue in production ?

Comment: You can check your application logs. They're usually located in `"#{RAILS_ROOT}/logs/production.log"`.

Comment: If you are on linux or mac don't open them with the text editor! Usually those files are huge and sometimes your editor will crash -  try to [less them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can track issues in production in various way. There are several answers available. But better I should share very common practice regarding a rails application. If you are using apache/nginx as your http server. You can tail there log and make the operation on browser on the same time so you can get realtime log from the http server.

Next, based on your configuration (as per convention over configuration) there should be production.log in your app log directory. You can run the following command in your terminal/command line tools and check the log on real time:

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

I assumed in your case production.log is the log file currently logging everything by your production application server (passenger/unicorn/puma/etc..)

For assets and client end issues, try using your browser's console to inspect the issues.

I hope my answer will give you some idea!